# Simulating swaps on ETH through web3.py

Tags: uniswap, web3.py, scam, bot

I'll expose my problem to you : I'm working on a sniping bot, which detects new liquidity pools on Uniswap v2. But since all the new created pairs are new token/WETH like, i need to be able to check wether this new token is a scam or not. To check if it's a honey pot (which is the most common), i've tried to simulate the swap back transaction (new token for WETH), but since i don't have any new token in my ballance, even the simulation fails.
At this time I don't have many ideas left. The thing is I can't request an API for that, for it would take too long to response, and my bot needs to be fast :')
I was wondering if it was possible to simulate a fake amount of token in my balance, just the time of the eth.call(), or if someone had any other idea.

Here is the code I've done for the check so far :

```py
def check_scam(wallet : Wallet, rooter : Contract, weth : Token, token : Token):
    amountIn = wallet.get_token_balance(token) // 10
    print(f"Amount in: {amountIn / (10 ** token.decimals)}")
    swap_out_params = {
        'amountIn' : amountIn,
        'amountOutMin' : 0,
        'path' : [token.address, weth.address],
        'to' : wallet.account.address,
        'deadline' : int(time.time() + 15 * 60)
    }
    
    swap_function = rooter.contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(**swap_out_params)

    # Define the transaction
    swap_out_tx = swap_function.build_transaction({
        'from': wallet.account.address,
        'gas': 250000,
        'gasPrice': (rooter.w3.eth.gas_price * 2),
        'nonce': rooter.w3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet.account.address),
    })

    try:
        rooter.w3.eth.call(swap_out_tx)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    
    print("Could swap out successfully")
```

Thank you for your help !